# Quantum mechanics and gender of unborn baby

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition, thought-experiment, schroedingers-cat

Having a debate with my other half here, I'm currently pregnant and we have not had any scans or tests to determine gender of the baby.

I'm seeing this as similar to a [Schroedinger's cat experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger's_cat) in that my baby is both male and female until it is determined either way. However my partner believes that it is unequivocally fixed because the sperm and egg determined the gender, the fact that it has not yet been observed is irrelevant.

I know that this is all mainly theory but I wanted to get a physicist's opinion. How determined is my baby's gender right now?

Comment: Hi Fiona, I don't think its 0ff topic to wish you all the best in the next few months, (and hopefully college fees are not astronomical in 18 years time.)

Comment: I'm afraid that your other half is correct, and your baby's gender has already been determined in the quantum-mechanical sense.  Your macroscopic womb has already performed the necessary "scan."  Schrodinger's cat is ontological, not epistemological - it has nothing to do with what any human being does or does not know.  See my answer to the duplicate question for more detail.

But enough boring physics talk - congratulations!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just like to emphasise what Conifold pointed out, which is that your baby's gender *was* determined at the time of fertilisation. This is the absolute key in understanding the difference between quantum superposition and, in this case, your baby's gender. It's not even to do with how many particles a system contains.

When Conifold said "uncertain", what was meant was that it wasn't just our lack of knowledge, but the cat *really* has no determined state. It is neither alive, nor dead. But your baby clearly already has a fixed gender - if we imagine having identical copies of the same egg and the same sperm that forms your baby, no matter how many times we perform the experiment, the outcome will be the same. However, if we do the Schrodinger cat experiment numerous times, sometimes the cat will be dead when we look, and sometimes alive.

Answer (score 3):

Schroedinger's Cat is a thought experiment and an analogy used to explain superposition and indeterminacy. Instead of a cat you should actually understand a quantum system. This system is under the rules of Quantum Mechanics and in the thought experiment it is in a superposition of two states (live and dead, up and down, whatever, those are just labels). Once you measure the system (open the box) you project the superposed state into one of its components (live or dead).

Now it comes to the question: Is a fetus, or even a zygote, a quantum mechanical system? It is definitely small but yet too big to show effects originated from state superposition. Otherwise one would detect a interference pattern in a double slit experiment made out of cells. This has never been observed. The largest structure showing such a quantum mechanical effect is a structure called [bucky-ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckminsterfullerene) which is made out of 60 atoms. On the other hand, a single cell has approximately $10^{14}$ atoms. That is too much to show quantum effects. So the zygote is not in a superposition of states (male and female) and the baby genre's is determined right after the fecundation.